# How to copy rows based on multiple email addresses?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge list of data and column 3 contains email addresses.

I'm trying to copy rows based on a mailing list. As long as the row contains one of the email addresses in the mailing list it should be copied to a new sheet.

I have code to copy data based on one email at a time.

I have a userform set up for several email addresses, but this is not efficient.

Here is my code that uses one email address at a time.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To a
    
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = "<@gmail.com>" Then
        
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

            b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row                
            
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select        
            ActiveSheet.Paste                
            
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    
        End If
    Next
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```

How to copy rows based on multiple emails addresses?

Comment: Not so clear. Will you need to copy all the cells in column C that have emails..?or I misunderstand you ..? Give a snapshot of the worksheet.

Comment: You can replace the copy, activate, select and paste code by something like `Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 3).Value`

Comment: Where is your mailing list? How is it stored?

Comment: @YasserKhalil i need to copy only rows in which column C (which contains email address) matches emails in a mailing list that I have. so say I have an email list that has (email 1, email2, email3). I want to copy all rows that  if column C  = email1 or email 2 or email 3 and then past them to sheet 2.

Comment: If you use the Advanced Filter, you don't even need VBA.  If you use the AutoFilter, you can copy/paste the visible range after filtering in a single step.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the `Advanced Filter`  The destination range will get written in a single step.  If you can minimize the number of times your code reads/writes to/from a worksheet, the faster it will run.

**Sheet 1**

[image]

Read the comments in the code as they will be important for modifying it to your real data.

In particular, if your column 3 list does not have the same format as what you have shown in your code, you will need to modify the Criteria range to account for that.  The Advanced Filter can also accept wild-cards in the criteria, so this might be another possible approach if your column 3 contains actual email addresses.

```
Option Explicit
Sub copyWithEmail()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rSrc As Range, rDest As Range, rCrit As Range
    Dim arrCrit As Variant
    Dim I As Long

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsDest = Worksheets("sheet2")

With wsDest
    .Cells.Clear 'optional
    Set rCrit = .Cells(1, 250) 'someplace off the screen view
    Set rDest = .Cells(1, 1)
End With

'assumes original data starts in A1
'assumes first row is a header row
Set rSrc = wsSrc.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

'can get list of desired emails from user form; range someplace in the workbook; or hard-coded as we have here
arrCrit = Array("gmail.com", "abc.com")
    For I = 0 To UBound(arrCrit)

        'creating formula that mimics what you show in your code above.
        arrCrit(I) = "=" & """=<@" & arrCrit(I) & ">"""
    Next I

'create criteria range
'header is same header as in Source Data column 3
Set rCrit = rCrit.Resize(2 + UBound(arrCrit))
    rCrit(1) = rSrc(1, 3)
    rCrit.Offset(1).Resize(rCrit.Rows.Count - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrCrit)

'Activate wsDest since we will be copying here
wsDest.Activate

rSrc.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=rCrit, CopyToRange:=rDest, Unique:=False
rDest.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
rCrit.Clear 'get rid of this range
End Sub
```

**Sheet 2**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be something like having Sheet3 of mialList and then

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet, Sh3 As Worksheet, fnd As Range, cl As Range
Set Sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set Sh3 = Worksheets("Sheet3")

Dim mailList As Range
x = Sh3.Range("A" & Sh3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set mailList = Sh3.Range("A2:A" & x)
'Assuming headers in row 1

For Each cl In mailList
    b = Sh2.Range("A" & Sh2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set fnd = Sh1.Columns(3).Find(cl)
    If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
    Sh2.Rows(b).Value = Sh1.Rows(fnd.Row).Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: yes .. you are right .. range.find would be a better option may be